# solr - Facet equal to number of occurences instead of number of documents

Tags: solr, nosql, faceted-search

My problem is that I want to compute the `facets` (or counts each `value`) for a `multivalued` `field`, and taking into account that this `value` can appear more that once inside this `multivalued` field.

Simple facets return `documents` count without computing the number of occurences of this `value` inside each document.

Comment: How many documents are we talking about? It might be possible to build a separate core to facet against, where each term is a separate document?

Comment: maybe tens or hundreds of documents. Do you mean that I have to build this separate core at index time?

Comment: Tens or hundreds of documents total in the index? Sounds rather small. :-) Yes, that is my suggestion at the current time; you could probably do something with the term frequence for the document and then add that, but I don't think anything like that exists already, so you might have to make a plugin for it - if possible. Doing a separate index would allow you to solve it what you have available today with a bit of application logic.

Comment: So far, I have never used more than one collection as an index. Is it possible to have `two` collections which have a certain `relation` between them (`a foreign key`)?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping them separate for now anyway, and just use one collection for generating the facet counts.

Comment: thanks @fiskfisk, I dont know how to use two separate collections anyway. I guess that I have learn to do some `nosql` stuff

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what `value` may be(single char, word, phrase, etc.) and some simple example of what do you want to get as the result?

Comment: @rchukh, for example I have `documents` that represent `football games` with a `multivalued` field for `goalscorers`. Obviously, In this field, a single `goalscorer(player)` can score multiple times in the same `game(match)`.

Comment: Ah, so you want to get e.g. "John Doe - 2, Jane Doe - 1" for first document(game), "Jack Doe - 4" for second game, and so on, correct?

Comment: That's right. I guess that it's impossible!